# Which character is displayed in my profile overview?

Tags: path-of-exile

Which one of my characters is displayed in my [profile overview](https://www.pathofexile.com/account/view-profile/ponyfan)?

Can I choose which one to display?

Answer (score 4):

It's the highest level characters in a hardcore and a softcore league.
No, you can't choose.

(according to [this forum post](https://www.pathofexile.com/forum/view-thread/1980130/page/1#p14815139))